# Remote desktop protocole with Angular application

Tags: remote-desktop, angular

I need to display an external machine's desktop inside my angular 6 application, so I should have a connection to that machine via rdp protocole(I guess) , any ideas on how to achieve that ? I tried many packages like 
[ngx-remote-desktop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@illgrenoble/ngx-remote-desktop) based on guacamole server , but it's really complicated to get guacamole running on windows. Any suggestions or ideas for an alternative solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about running [Guacamole in Docker](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/guacamole-docker.html) on your Windows machine?

Comment: Any progress on that isuue ?